# Different Behaviour of Excel files while loading the data into one table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, excel-2013, ssis-2012

I am having issue while loading the data from Excel to the sql server using ssis or also using the Import and Export Wizard
The thing is that in one Excel , the data with Error (or to say Warning symbol) cell in the sheet is getting populated and in the other case this is not getting populated !! I dont know why Excel is behaving diffrently.. I want to know what can be done to achieve this even though you have or dont have "Warning" symbol in the Excel Sheet cells

I even tried converting the .xlsx to .xls format too but didnt worked.

Comment: Are you saying one particular Excel file is not loaded into your table? When you run the SSIS package interactively do you get any errors?

Comment: well two excel files one table and so one package but two DFTs..but for one excel whose cells are perfect with formating are getting loaded and in another excel file the perfect formating cells are not getting populated instead "Warning" symbol gets populated

Comment: and when you run the package interactively are they loaded or does an error occur?

Comment: they all are loaded but with NULL values and not actual data

Comment: It sounds like the curse of IMEX. If you search on `IMEX=1` you will find many many articles about it. The exclamation mark might have nothing to do with it, but anyway: if you double click the source does the exclamation mark go away? if not what error appears in the tooltip (also in the warnings ouptut)? Do have any option to load data out of text files instead of Excel?

Comment: Haha, but there is no exclamation in the cells where i am receiving the Warning if i double click inside that cell , that warning symbol goes off and it will get displayed as normal value
http://postimg.org/image/lvwvd76rd/

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you meant exclamation mark in the SSIS package. I'm having difficulty understanding what you're getting at. Where exactly do you see this exclamation mark? In SSIS, in the Excel formula or  on a cell or on the actual Excel file. I'm searching on 'exclamation mark' to try and understand what you mean.

Comment: Please check this link 
http://postimg.org/image/mwp7ljr3z/
the first row is not having the Warning and then the 2nd,3rd and 4th cells are having Warning symbol which is a format issue. The one with Warnings are not getting populated sometimes and sometimes the one without warning are getting populated

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's an IMEX issue. Take a look at this: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/mixed-data-types-in-excel-column.html. Sepcifically this part: _Goto the properties of the Excel Connection manager and change the ConnectionString property:_
`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\MyExcelFile1.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";`

Comment: Well, tried like that too but the output is the same

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is your issue. I'm out of ideas. I don't have much patience for excel as a data source or data transfer mechanism.

Comment: Got U Nick ..Thanks for the Help !!!! Will post you if any info from my side :)

Comment: Good luck. If you find an answer by all means post back and make the internet a smarter place!!!